# AUTOTOOLS : use my own testsuite instead of the default one

Tags: testing, binary, output, autotools, test-suite

I have made a python testsuite to test my project. I have added in `Makefile.am` the variable:

```
TESTS = ./launcher.sh
```

launcher.sh contains: `tests/testsuite.py`

When I do `./launcher.sh`, my testsuite is correctly executed.
However, when I do `make check`, I get the following output:

```
PASS: launcher.sh
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for spider 1.0
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

How can I hide the default output and use the output of my testsuite ?

Answer (score 0):

The Automake manual contains [a whole chapter on testing](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tests.html#Tests), which would be helpful for understanding the context of Automake's test suite support.  Moreover, it is important to understand that part of the bargain you enter into by using Automake to generate makefiles for you is to accept some limitations on the form and behavior of the resulting build system.

> How can I hide the default output and use the output of my testsuite ?

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot hide the default output of `make check`, but you *can* cause the output of your test program to be emitted to `make`'s standard output instead of redirected to a file.  The easiest way to do this would be to enable [the serial test harness](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Serial-Test-Harness.html#Serial-Test-Harness) by turning on Automake's `serial-tests` option.  That would ordinarily be expressed via the argument to the `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` macro in your `configure.ac`:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([serial-tests])
```

Note also that it should not be necessary to wrap your `tests/testsuite.py` in a shell script.  Just make sure it is executable (which it sounds like you have already done), and name it directly, relative path included, in the value of the `TESTS` variable.